# Samsung Tab2 without Google ID

Tags: google-account, samsung-galaxy-tab, privacy

Is it possible to use a Samsung Tab WITHOUT using a Google account? I don't like Google to monitor all my activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. When you first boot the device, it asks for your Google account. Just select the option "I don't have a Google account" and then the option that says you don't want to create one.

Note that you can't use some Google services like Play Store which require a Google account.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I can ignore the Play Store and install certain apps via the website of the developer?

Comment: Yes; there are other app market apps too, including Samsung's own. Don't forget to click **Ask Question** if you have a follow-up question to ask.

Comment: You might also want to check [F-Droid](http://f-droid.org/), which is a FOSS (free-and-open-source) Android market. They have their own "market app" which you can find on the linked website, install on your device (after having enabled "unknown sources" in your settings), and then enjoy an alternative market app -- without having a Google Account.